# What is backup mode in Robocopy

Tags: windows, file-transfer, robocopy

I am trying to copy a large database backup file over network.

The `.net FileInfo.CopyTo` or `xcopy` failed with different binary resulted. Also tried `robocopy` without parameter, and resulted a failure. Just did another attempt with `robocopy` using `/zb` parameter (restart and backup mode). It took much longer but resulted in a success.

My question is, is backup mode in `robocopy` really designed to copy large / backup file? Have searched through net and couldn't find a clear answer.

Would appreciate if any experienced user could give me a hint or better solution on large file copy over network. Thanks.

Comment: Could it be some corruption making the file unreadable? Could it some interference like being locked by some antivirus program?  How about removing file extension and try again?

Comment: Yes the file is corrupted and removing file extension doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to share an update on resolving the issue above.

In my case, `xcopy` failed to copy the file over 10GB across servers in different domain and server location.

On the other side, `robocopy` with

`/zb` *- Uses Restart mode. If access is denied, this option uses Backup mode.*

can successfully copy. It increased the time from 1hour to 2.5hours though.

--

After re-arranging server, the file is copied across servers in the same domain and server location now. And using `xcopy` is alright too.

--

So my theory on this would be probably about the stability connection between servers. If the connection is not robust (with occasionally drop out causing an access issue), when copying large file like my case, a corruption likely occurs any time during the long process; `robocopy` with **restart and backup** can recover the copy pretty well. Time spent on recovery is probably the down side.

And as a side note, FTP instead of copy should be used if it's going to be a routine task.

Comment: This is not a correct answer, the next answer is actually the correct one. Sorry for answering an old post. 
Regarding the restartability - /z flag is responsible for it. For the unstable connection it should be enough to use only it. According to https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html both modes introduce a performance hit

Answer (score 1):

**Backup mode** only allows Robocopy to back up and restore all files, regardless of their own individual permissions (NTFS ACLs) on those files.